# Parked domain not being redirected

Tags: http, redirect, dns

I own a domain, **pricipal.com**. When I try to access it the redirect link gets stuck. I see in Chrome Developer tools that URL has status code 400. What causes this failure and how can I trouble shoot it?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general webserver tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of the failure: A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules

"redirect link gets stuck" ..

There are two type of solution one is simply removing cache and cookie of your browser. Another is little bit difficult. Try to set up your dns properly. If you are using CPANEL, sometimes ROOT User or admin of the server change addon/parked domain default directory which usually create redirecting loop.In short Servers Wrong configuration may cause this trouble. Try to park another domain and see what happen if that domain show you the same error contact with your server administrator

Comment: Thank you very much @SMJobayerAlam

Comment: `import requests
try:
    r = requests.head("http://pizzhut.com")
    print(r.status_code)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("failed to connect")`
I'm sorry to follow up with this so late but howcome I get 302 returuned here when in the browser its 400?